# Jenkins Repository connector Plugin Error "failed to expand tokens for [Artifact filename:ear::version]"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Can someone please help me with this error?

Jenkins version is 1.624

Plugin version is 1.1.1

```
failed to expand tokens for [Artifact filename:ear::version]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.aether.Aether.convertHudsonNonProxyToJavaNonProxy(Aether.java:151)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.aether.Aether.addProxySelectorIfNecessary(Aether.java:139)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.aether.Aether.newSession(Aether.java:183)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.aether.Aether.resolve(Aether.java:189)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.ArtifactResolver.download(ArtifactResolver.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.repositoryconnector.ArtifactResolver.perform(ArtifactResolver.java:101)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Build step 'Artifact Resolver' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved....

There was a proxy nexus server setup in  Jenkins

Jenkins - manage jenkins - manage plugins- advanced tab

removed the proxy server settings and defined the artifact resolver build step in the jenkins job ...worked fine

```
Fail on error check the box

Enable repository logging   -donot check box
```

Target directory- leave this empty

Release update policy-always

Snapshot update policy-always

Group Id-ear file group id

Artifact Id-ear fil aritfact id

Version- can be parameterized or use "LATEST"

```
Extension-ear
```

Target file name-full ear file name

worked fine plugin 1.1.1 has no issues.